Getting descriptive statistics in R for subsamples
I want to generate one single exportable table in R with descriptive statistics for: the whole sample and 3 sub-samples.
The variables I want to get the descriptive statistics for are:
MATCH_EFFECTS
%_EQUITY_VS_TDC1
AGE_THEN
FIRM_SIZE
B_T_M_RATIO
LEVERAGE

The variables to subset the data are. If their value is 1, it should generate a subset.
FIRST_YEAR_IS_FISCAL_YEAR
FIRST_CONTRACT_<2_Y_SWITCH
CEO_IS_FAMILIAR

Now I have this code which generates descriptive statistics for the whole sample
# Specify the variables for which you want descriptive statistics**
variables <- c("MATCH_EFFECTS", "%_EQUITY_VS_TDC1", "FIRST_YEAR_IS_FISCAL_YEAR", "FIRST_CONTRACT_<2_Y_SWITCH", "CEO_IS_FAMILIAR", "AGE_THEN", "FIRM_SIZE", "B_T_M_RATIO", "LEVERAGE")

# Generate descriptive statistics using vtable
st(DATASET_FINAL_R[variables])

But I want to get a table like the one added as output, but then with the whole sample and three sub-samples.


vtable author here. You can almost get this with vtable::st() using the group option (and group.test = TRUE to get sig. differences between them). But by default that pus the switchers/others side-by-side instead of one-above-the-other, or with group.long = TRUE separates them into two tables, one on top of the other. If that works, great! If not, getting sumtable to make this exact table is possible but would be really wonky and you'd probably just be better using a different package or making it by hand.
